# Errors converting PDF with Imagemagick on Ubuntu 18

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript

On Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS on Azure with a Bitnami WordPress stack, I'm trying to get Imagemagick and Ghostscript working so WordPress will create PDF thumbnails. A simple conversion test gives an error. When I search on the error messages, they take me further and further down various rabbit holes about missing libraries, manually adding symlinks, compiling from source, etc. Doesn't seem like it should be that hard to run a popular image conversion program. What am I missing?

Here are the versions and the failing test:

```
/tmp$ sudo apt update
All packages are up to date.
/tmp$ sudo apt install imagemagick
imagemagick is already the newest version (8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16ubuntu6.8).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
/tmp$ sudo apt install ghostscript
ghostscript is already the newest version (9.26~dfsg+0-0ubuntu0.18.04.12).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

/tmp$ which convert
/opt/bitnami/common/bin/convert
/tmp$ convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.8-3 Q16 x86_64 2019-04-03 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2017 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules
Delegates (built-in): bzlib freetype jng jpeg ltdl png tiff wmf xml zlib

/tmp$ which ghostscript
/usr/bin/ghostscript
/tmp$ gs -version
GPL Ghostscript 9.26 (2018-11-20)
Copyright (C) 2018 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.

/tmp$ convert -verbose resume.pdf resume.jpg
'gs' -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 '-sDEVICE=pngalpha' -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 '-r72x72'  '-sOutputFile=/tmp/magick-38144ceME6-csnc4X%d' '-f/tmp/magick-38144tpfIz6n76qfI' '-f/tmp/magick-38144AH22zQfdNQqs'
gs: /opt/bitnami/common/lib/libtiff.so.5: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgs.so.9)
gs: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgs.so.9: undefined symbol: FT_Property_Set
.convert.bin: no images defined `resume.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.
```

---

**Edit** As requested in comments:

```
~$ echo $LD_LIBARY_PATH

~$ ldd $(which conver)
ldd: missing file arguments
Try `ldd --help' for more information.
~$ ldd $(which convert)
        not a dynamic executable
~$ ldd /usr/bin/ghostscript
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffc5be3000)
        libgs.so.9 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgs.so.9 (0x00007f3614e95000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3614aa4000)
        libtiff.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5 (0x00007f361482d000)
        libcupsimage.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcupsimage.so.2 (0x00007f3614624000)
        libcups.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcups.so.2 (0x00007f3614398000)
        libijs-0.35.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libijs-0.35.so (0x00007f3614192000)
        libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f3613f60000)
        libjbig2dec.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjbig2dec.so.0 (0x00007f3613d48000)
        libjpeg.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8 (0x00007f3613ae0000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f36138c3000)
        liblcms2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblcms2.so.2 (0x00007f361366b000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f36132cd000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f36130c9000)
        libidn.so.11 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11 (0x00007f3612e96000)
        libpaper.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpaper.so.1 (0x00007f3612c92000)
        libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f3612a4d000)
        libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f3612799000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f361257a000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3616241000)
        liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f3612354000)
        libjbig.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjbig.so.0 (0x00007f3612146000)
        libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f3611efb000)
        libgnutls.so.30 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 (0x00007f3611b95000)
        libavahi-common.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavahi-common.so.3 (0x00007f3611989000)
        libavahi-client.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavahi-client.so.3 (0x00007f3611778000)
        libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f3611546000)
        libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f3611270000)
        libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f361103e000)
        libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f3610e3a000)
        libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f3610c2f000)
        libp11-kit.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007f3610900000)
        libidn2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0 (0x00007f36106e3000)
        libunistring.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2 (0x00007f3610365000)
        libtasn1.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x00007f3610152000)
        libnettle.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6 (0x00007f360ff1c000)
        libhogweed.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4 (0x00007f360fce8000)
        libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007f360fa67000)
        libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007f360f81a000)
        libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f360f616000)
        libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f360f3fb000)
        libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f360f1f3000)
        libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007f360ef6f000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f360ed67000)
        liblz4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007f360eb4b000)
        libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007f360e82f000)
        libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f360e61a000)
```

Comment: Why do you have */opt/bitnami/common/lib/libtiff.so.5* ? You have library mess - please add output of `echo $LD_LIBARY_PATH`, `ldd $(which conver)`, `ldd /usr/bin/ghostscript` to the question body by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1258602/edit).

Comment: Remove the imagemagicks installation you added yourself under /opt. Then, the system will revert to the standard version that comes with the distribution, and then it will, as you expect, not be hard anymore to run that popular image conversion program.

Comment: Thanks. The version of ImageMagick under /opt/bitnami is part of the Bitnami stack. I just found a similar issue reported in 2017 on the Bitnami forum [here](https://community.bitnami.com/t/unable-to-install-image-magick/51769/15). I'll try posting on that forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting this question on the Bitnami forum, I received the [suggestion](https://community.bitnami.com/t/imagemagick-errors-wordpress-cant-create-pdf-thumbnails/83355/2?u=mcbsys2) to uninstall Ghostscript 9.26 and upload the 9.27 binary directly from the Github to the server's path. To my surprise, this immediately allowed Imagemagick to work. PDF thumbnail generation in WordPress is working too.

Based on [this post](https://community.bitnami.com/t/imagemagick-not-working-out-of-the-box/68902/18), here are the commands I used to uninstall Ghostscript and get the 9.27 binary from Github:

```
$ sudo apt remove ghostscript
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-droid-fallback fonts-noto-mono libcupsfilters1 libcupsimage2 libgs9 libgs9-common
  libijs-0.35 libjbig2dec0 libpaper-utils libpaper1 poppler-data
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ghostscript
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
After this operation, 229 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 128918 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing ghostscript (9.26~dfsg+0-0ubuntu0.18.04.12) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
~$ $ cd /tmp && curl -LO https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/download/gs927/ghostscript-9.27-linux-x86_64.tgz
$: command not found
~$ cd /tmp && curl -LO https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/download/gs927/ghostscript-9.27-linux-x86_64.tgz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   644  100   644    0     0   2730      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2775
100 11.5M  100 11.5M    0     0  7733k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 21.9M
/tmp$ tar -xzf ghostscript-9.27-linux-x86_64.tgz
/tmp$ sudo mv ghostscript-9.27-linux-x86_64/gs-927-linux-x86_64 /usr/local/bin/gs
/tmp$ rm -r ghostscript-9.27-linux-x86_64 ghostscript-9.27-linux-x86_64.tgz
/tmp$ gs -version
GPL Ghostscript 9.27 (2019-04-04)
Copyright (C) 2018 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
/tmp$ convert -verbose resume.pdf resume.jpg
'gs' -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 '-sDEVICE=pngalpha' -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 '-r72x72'  '-sOutputFile=/tmp/magick-27002C4cvCbSgCyYC%d' '-f/tmp/magick-27002GcI2PwMTOpvp' '-f/tmp/magick-2700234-pb9vPGw2b'
/tmp/magick-27002C4cvCbSgCyYC1 PNG 594x774 594x774+0+0 8-bit sRGB 28.3KB 0.030u 0:00.039
/tmp/magick-27002C4cvCbSgCyYC2 PNG 594x774 594x774+0+0 8-bit sRGB 25.3KB 0.040u 0:00.030
resume.pdf[0] PDF 594x774 594x774+0+0 16-bit sRGB 28.3KB 0.040u 0:00.030
resume.pdf[1] PDF 594x774 594x774+0+0 16-bit sRGB 28.3KB 0.000u 0:00.000
resume.pdf=>resume-0.jpg[0] PDF 594x774 594x774+0+0 16-bit Bilevel Gray 133KB 0.030u 0:00.050
resume.pdf=>resume-1.jpg[1] PDF 594x774 594x774+0+0 16-bit Bilevel Gray 122KB 0.060u 0:00.079
```